# How to use a stop condition on a block like the enumerateObjectsUsingBlock from the NSDictionary class?

Tags: objective-c, pass-by-reference, objective-c-blocks

I want to make a method on my class like `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)` from the `NSDictionary` class.

I have a little knowledge on blocks usage, but I have not been able to figure out how to make the stop condition that the `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` function uses. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `stop` flag is used like this:

```
[coll enumerateUsingBlock:^(id o, NSUInteger i, BOOL *stop) {
      if (... check for stop ... ) {
           *stop = YES;
           return;
      }
 }];
```

When the enumeration block returns, the collection checks `*stop`.  If it is `YES`, it stops enumerating.

It is implemented this way, as opposed to a return value, because this allows for concurrent enumeration without checking the return value of the block (which would incur overhead).  I.e. in concurrent enumeration, the collection can `dispatch_async()` any number of simultaneous iterations and periodically check `*stop`.   Whenever `*stop` transitions to `YES`, it stops scheduling more blocks (this is also why the `stop` flag is not a hard stop;  some unspecified number of iterations may still be in flight).

In your iterator, you might do:

```
 BOOL stop = NO;
 for(...) {
     enumerationBlock(someObj, someIndex, &stop);
     if (stop) break;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. The solution to this question can also be found here: http://www.informit.com/blogs/blog.aspx?uk=Ask-Big-Nerd-Ranch-Blocks-in-Objective-C

Answer (score 6):

The following code defines a method that takes a block as a parameter and keeps executing it until `shouldStop` is set to `NO` by the block.

```
- (void)myMethod:(void(^)(BOOL *stop))aBlock {
    BOOL shouldStop = NO;
    while (!shouldStop) {
        aBlock(&shouldStop);
    }
}
```

The explanation is fairly simple. A block is a function that takes some parameters. In this case we pass as a parameter a pointer to a `BOOL` variable we own. By doing so we are allowing the block to set that variable and - in this case - indicate that the loop should stop.

At this point, the block passed could do something like

```
[self myMethod:^(BOOL *stop) {
      if (arc4random_uniform(1)) {
          *stop = YES;
      }
}];
```